# Kendo multiselect cross icon issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-multiselect

I am using Kendo multiselect. I am facing issue while removing selected items using cross icon which are coming in kendo multi select at right hand side as shown in image below,

[image]

as per above image it is showing 8 item selected in drop down so to remove selected items when I click on highlighted cross icon it is removing item one by one but it should clear all selection when click on highlighted cross icon.

below is my code that I have written for drop down.

```
 <select id="RegionDDL" kendo-multi-select="" k-options="RegionOptions" k-ng-delay="RegionOptions"
                                                        k-ng-model="CommonFilter.Regions"></select>

 $scope.RegionOptions = {
                    autoBind: false,
                    placeholder: "Select All",
                    dataTextField: "Text",
                    dataValueField: "ID",
                    filter: "contains",
                    tagMode: "single",
                    change: OnRegionChange,
                    // ************ Below commented to remove cascading functionality *************
                    //filtering: function (e) { $scope.callDataBoundFn = false; },
                    dataBound: function (e) {
                        current = this.value();
                        this._savedOld = current.slice(0);
                        // handle the event
                    },
                    dataSource: $scope.RegionDataSource
                };

  $scope.RegionDataSource = {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: window.versionType + "api/GetRegions",
                            headers: {
                                "Authorization": "Bearer " + sessionStorage["accessToken"],
                                "coreInfo": JSON.stringify(coreInfo)
                            },
                            dataType: "json",
                        }
                    }
                };
```

Please help.

Comment: can you also share which kendo version you are using?

Comment: Kendo UI v2017.1.223